# JMeter : Recording Local Web Application using HTTP Proxy Help needed

Tags: .net, jmeter

I'm facing a serious problem from past 1 week. I will explain my scenario very clearly.

I have created a WebApplication in ASP.NET and deplOyed in to my local IIS with default Port 80.I want to run **JMeter** Testing for that.

Obstacles which i have from my side are,

1) I'm working under Corporate Network. Basic internet itself is with proxy. say my internet connection will work only if apply `host:<abcproxy> and port:<someportnumber>`

2) None of my localhost application will be resolved with this proxy so i have to bypass proxy in order to view web application which i have deployed in my local IIS.
I have used http://www.roseindia.net/jmeter/using-jmeter.shtml this site as my reference and it is working fine. But i'm not able to record because i want to use **HTTPProxy**. If i use HTTP Proxy then i have to give port number for listening. If i give port number in `WorkBench->HTTPProxy` then i cant give same port number because the port number which i have given on http proxy wont work on my browser. If i give default port number 80 in **HTTPProxy** then **JMeter** won't work (it says Port number is already in use. Try different Port number-reason is my IIS is using that port number.)
Please suggest me some solution to record testing using HTTPProxy or suggest me is there anyother way we can record. Even small answers will be great helpful to me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at this document I think you will find it very usefull.

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf

This will give you a more in depth explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [this](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server):

> If you are testing from behind a firewall/proxy server, you may need to provide JMeter with the firewall/proxy server hostname and port number. To do so, run the jmeter.bat/jmeter file from a command line with the following parameters:
>
> -H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
>
> -P [proxy server port]
>
> -N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
>
> -u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> -a [password for proxy authentication - if required]
>
> Example : jmeter -H my.proxy.server -P 8000 -u username -a password -N localhost
>
> Alternatively, you can use --proxyHost, --proxyPort, --username, and --password

Comment: I have done that and i'm running through that only... And alos i told that i'm able to run Test but i'm not able to record... thank you

Comment: Can you post the list of parameters you use when starting jMeter?